# Button is Disabled for some seconds perfectly which I needed, but form is not submitted again Through that button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Button is Disabled for some seconds perfectly which I needed, but form is not submitted again Through that button.**

*Here Is Script Code written in head tag*

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.myform').on('submit', function () {
                $('.output_message').text('Loading...');
                var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    method: form.attr('method'),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result == 'success') {
                            $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');
                            $(".output_message").show();
                            $('.output_message').fadeOut(3000);
                            $('#btn').on('click', function () {
                                $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                                }, 3000); // 3 seconds 
                            });

                        } else {
                            $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you add details on what you would like to do and what your HTML looks like

Comment: Please clarify "form is not submitted again Through that button". Do you want the form to be submitted twice after pressing the button once?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this instead.

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }, 3000); // 3 seconds 
});
```

Since you haven't provided the complete code, I can't tell the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I Just Replaced**

```
                        $('#btn').on('click', function () {
                            $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                            }, 3000); // 3 seconds 
                        });
```

**With**

```
                            $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $('[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                            }, 3000); // 3 seconds
```

*Now It is working*